# The multi-part identifier "Event.dbo.Events.UTCTime" could not be bound

Tags: sql, select

There is a lot of questions regarding this error message type, but I have not found -or maybe not understood- any answers on this specific case.

I have an application that can connect to custom database and retrieve data within a certain time span.  Sort order can also be set.

Different views can be used to retrieve data and the application shall not have any knowledge of which columns that exists in the view.

But the application must know which column in the underlying table that shall be used to find the time span and which column in the underlying table that shall be used to set sort order.

How can I do that when I do not want this information to be returned as a part of the “select” statement?

```
/*--------- This is an example of view in the custom database ------------*/
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[EventViewFull]
AS

SELECT         
                dbo.[Events].[Time], 
                dbo.[Events].MicroSec, 
                dbo.[Events].Seq, 
                dbo.Redundancy.Redundancy,
                dbo.OrigStation.OrigStation, 
                dbo.Priority.Priority, 
                dbo.EventType.EventType, 
                dbo.CommGrp.CommGrp, 
                dbo.AlarmState.AlarmState, 
                dbo.[Events].Acked, 
                dbo.Names1.Name1, 
                dbo.Names2.Name2, 
                dbo.[Events].EventText, 
                dbo.[Events].[Description], 
                dbo.[Events].AddInfo, 
                dbo.[Events].Members
FROM           
                dbo.[Events] 
                INNER JOIN dbo.Names1       ON dbo.[Events].Name1_ID        = dbo.Names1.Name1_ID
                INNER JOIN dbo.Names2       ON dbo.[Events].Name2_ID        = dbo.Names2.Name2_ID
                INNER JOIN dbo.AlarmState   ON dbo.[Events].AlarmState_NR   = dbo.AlarmState.AlarmState_NR      
                INNER JOIN dbo.EventType    ON dbo.[Events].EventType_NR    = dbo.EventType.EventType_NR        
                INNER JOIN dbo.CommGrp      ON dbo.[Events].CommGrp_NR      = dbo.CommGrp.CommGrp_NR            
                INNER JOIN dbo.Priority     ON dbo.[Events].Priority_NR     = dbo.Priority.Priority_NR  
                INNER JOIN dbo.OrigStation  ON dbo.[Events].OrigStation_NR  = dbo.OrigStation.OrigStation_NR    
                LEFT  JOIN dbo.Redundancy   ON dbo.[Events].OrigStation_NR  = dbo.Redundancy.Redun


/*--This is the not working query in the application. SQL server, database name, time span and view is input from the user -----*/

select * from EventViewFull 
where [Event].[dbo].[Events].UTCTime between '2012-11-18 23:0:0' and '2014-6-18 22:0:0' 
order by [Event].[dbo].[Events].UTCTime DESC, [Event].[dbo].[Events].Seq DESC

/*  Error messages I get with the current implementation of the script.
The multi-part identifier "Event.dbo.Events.UTCTime" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "Event.dbo.Events.Seq" could not be bound.
*/
```

Comment: You cannot reference the columns from other tables/views that are not part of the from clause in a select statement. In your query you are selecting from EventViewFull, which means you need to use only those columns that are part of this view. You cannot use [Event].[dbo].[Events].UTCTime in the where clause.

Comment: Yes, I know Kiran.
The question is how can I solve this issue when I not want the UTC time to be one of the columns returned.
I only want to use it to set the time span.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your problem properly

You can use the following query to return all the columns only from the view

```
select EventViewFull.* from EventViewFull 
join [Event].[dbo].[Events] ev ON EventViewFull.Seq = ev.Seq 
where ev.UTCTime between '2012-11-18 23:0:0' and '2014-6-18 22:0:0' 
order by ev.UTCTime DESC, ev.Seq DESC
```

This query will eliminate the error what you are getting at the moment. But I assumed Seq column as the primary key for the event. You need to change this to the correct column, if it is not the right one.
However as you can see the query, [Event].[dbo].[Events] is joined again with the view, even though the view has the information from the same table. It would be good to add UTCTime to the view, from the performance point of view, but not sure why does that not work for you.

Comment: Thank you very much Kiran for your effort.
I have tried out your suggestion.  Unfortunately it is very slow.  It uses 38 seconds before starting returning data -within timespan "A".
I will add the UTCTime column to the select statement and live with that solution.
If I do that a request -within timespan "A"- takes < 1 second.
Thank you very much for trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

I had to add UTCTime and Seq to the select statement in the [dbo].[EventViewFull] event though I did not want UTCtime and Seq to be a part of the resulting data set, but I can live with it.